# Creating child relationship with reference fails via Composite Tree REST API

Tags: rest-api, childrelationship, reference

In my setup, Leads can have multiple Affiliates (custom object `Affiliate__c`), which is implemented through a child relationship and where each Affiliate consists of a name and the two related objects: The affiliated Lead and the affiliating Account.

When trying to create a Lead together with an (existing) Affiliate using the Composite Tree Resource and the following payload, it fails with a `Cannot reference a foreign key field Account__r.`

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Lead",
                "referenceId": "ref1"
            },
            "LastName": "Doe",
            "Lead_External_Id": "L1",
            "Affiliates__r": {
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Affiliate__c",
                            "referenceId": "ref2"
                        },
                        "Name": "First Affiliation",
                        "Account__r": {
                            "Id": "123456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, if I use the Composite Resource with the following payload, it works fine:

```
{
    "compositeRequest": [
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Lead",
            "referenceId": "ref1",
            "body": {
                "LastName": "Doe",
                "Lead_External_Id": "L1"
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Affiliate__c",
            "referenceId": "ref2",
            "body": {
                "Name": "First Affiliation",
                "Lead__r": {
                    "Lead_External_Id": "L1"
                },
                "Account__r": {
                    "Id": "123456"
                }
            }
        }       
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong when using the Composite Tree Resource? Is this resource not capable of creating a child relationship with a reference to another object?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late to answer, but you are right, Composite Tree resource must have only one parent object and their child within the tree.